# How do you access the primary key from a generic list view?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to access the primary key of the url from a generic list view. Let me explain. So, I currently have a simple page with a list of student instances from the model `student`. Each row is dedicated to one student, such as the name, age, email, etc. Now, I want to add a link to each row so that I can view each student's calendar once I clicked it. Right now, the calendar view is a generic ListView like below.

```
class CalendarView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    model = Class
    template_name = 'leads/calendar.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # use today's date for the calendar
        d = get_date(self.request.GET.get('month', None))
        # Instantiate our calendar class with today's year and date
        cal = Calendar(d.year, d.month)
        # Call the formatmonth method, which returns our calendar as a table
        html_cal = cal.formatmonth(withyear=True)
        context['calendar'] = mark_safe(html_cal)
        context['prev_month'] = prev_month(d)
        context['next_month'] = next_month(d)
        return context
```

However, I want the calendar to show only information related to the student I clicked on. In order to do this, I need to be able to use the primary key(or ID) of the student in my calendar view. Of course, I can embed the primary key in the url, but I have no idea how to access the pk in my generic.ListView. Also, I know some of you might suggest me to switch the view to a function, but I am not going to use a function as I did most of my coding with the generic version. I hope you guys can help, and give me any questions you have.

Here is the html template:

```
<a href="{% url 'calendar' lead.pk %}" class="text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-900">
                                        Calendar
                                    </a>
```

Here is the url:

```
path('personal/<int:pk>/calendar/', CalendarView.as_view(), name='calendar'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your url path is like so:

```
path('calendar/<int:studentId>/', CalendarView.as_view(), name='CalendarView'),
```

Then you can do:

```
class CalendarView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Class.objects.filter(student__id=self.kwargs['studentId'])
```

Comment: Thanks! but can I use `self.kwargs['studentId']` for `def get_context_data(self, **kwargs)`?

Comment: Also, this is kinda besides the point, but is it okay to have two urls for the same view? I want to use my calendar view when there is an additional pk and when there isn't.

Comment: Yes, it's ok. But you'll need to check if `self.kwargs['studentId']` exists for the case in which it doesn't.

Comment: Oh wait. I got this error: `django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'calendar' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['accounts/profile/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/calendar/$']`

Comment: Add one path with `studentId` and one without. Then in your template you should do `{% url 'calendar' %}` and `{% url 'calendar' pk=<some_student_id> %}` depending on the user case

Comment: I added the template and url above, but I am somehow still getting the same error... I don't know why.

Comment: why don't you explain things such as the double underscore for "student__id" in the answer? It's not really appropriate to say "you can do this" without explaining the mechanics of that